# how to add greater than,less than to a tag in xml file? as a sample <tag>&lt;mark&gt;</tag>

Tags: javascript, html, xml

when i'm trying to do what i wrote in title, the loading of xml Failed.

without those `"<",">"` the file loaded to the html with javascript great without  any problems.

i saw how w3c told to do that, but in case in title it Failed.

```
--1--
i can use
--2--
```

without problem and the xml file is loaded fine with the javascript into the html.

sample xml file:

```
--3--
that is looking like that in my browser:
--4-
```

what is the problem?

all the code parts are in this link http://pastebin.com/KaB8ifWz in parts 1/2/3/4

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help on how to format your questions, and include the samples from your pastebin here.

Comment: sorry the title was not the same as the xml file, look at the link now. i fixed the title now.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the part of XML containing tags with CDATA. e.g.

```
<![CDATA[<b>This part contains tags</b>]]>
```

Or:

```
<![CDATA[&lt;b&gt;This part contains tags&lt;/b&gt;]]>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for the answer: 1\<![CDATA[<b>This part contains tags</b>]]> and 2\<![CDATA[&lt;b&gt;This part contains tags&lt;/b&gt;]]> return Failed and i got black line instead